# Setting IP and Subnet in python

Tags: python, network-programming

I've been doing the programming for a start up company I know to get some experience. I've been told I'll need to relay data from my original piece of software running on one computer to 8 others using ethernet. Bear in mind I haven't really done much network stuff before.

I see that I'll need the python socket module so I've learned a bit of that. I also get that I'll need a network switch hardware-wise.

What I'm unsure about is how I set up the network in the first place. I get that I can do this via Device Manager but setting all computers to the same subnet and different IP addresses. However, the idea is that people will bring their laptops to be connected, so I don't want to have to mess around with each laptop to connect it to the network. So is there a way of doing this directly in Python so that I can just write it in the program that I'll have running on each laptop?

Thanks!

Comment: an ethernet wire only has 2 ends ...

Comment: that is what the switch is for I beleive

Comment: are you using a switch or a router? if its a router it should already have its own dhcp server? is this actually connected to the internet or just a local lan?

Comment: It'll be a local lan without internet connection. Using just a regular switch.

Comment: hadcode the ip of your device and run a socket server ... the other computers will need to know your ip ...

Comment: Yeah that's what I was planning. The problem is, from what I gather I'll need to set them all on the same subnet and give them ips manually. Since the computers are gonna be different each time, I dont want to have to do that with every single one, so I was looking for a way to do it from within python

Comment: this sounds like a flawed design in general ... there is probably a better way... if you use a router instead of a switch for example then they will all aquire their ip from the routers DHCP server (which will (more or less) ensure that they are on the same network ...)

Comment: Could I not set up a DHCP server on the computer which will be hosting the server? Switch has already been ordered :/

Answer (score 1):

You need a DHCP server and people's NIC's to retrieve their network configuration automatically.

Windows:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

Debian (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Red Hat (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0):

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```

I suppose you could use Python or whatever language you're convenient in to fetch the relevant interface's name, as they're not guaranteed to be named "eth0" or "Local Area Connection", e.g. subprocess.Popen("cat /proc/net/dev/").

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I feel like it's pointing me in the right direction, but I'm a bit of a noob at network stuff. So presumably I'd want to set up the DHCP server on the main computer that is distributing the data - but then how would the new computers know which subnet to be on in order to connect to the server computer?

Comment: They don't need to know the subnet. 

As long as their NIC's are set to DHCP, the protocol takes care of them being discovered on the network (via the [broadcast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address)). 

Once they're discovered, a DHCP request is sent. In return, the client receives whatever is set in the DHCP server (IP address, default gateway address, DNS address (optional)).